# How to stop sexual harassment by teacher?

Tags: india, sexual-misconduct, harassment, abuse

I'm a student in India.  My music teacher was kicked out of the school about 1 month ago due to sexual misconduct.

Today, he messaged me on Instagram with a fake ID and started talking nastily to me so I blocked him. He again messaged me with a new ID and asked for pictures and so on. I had to block him 3 more times.

He again messaged with a new ID of a girl. 
I gullibly replyed to the message but again he asked for pictures and some sexual chats so I blocked him once more.

This is not ending. He was my teacher and this attitude of his is not good.

What should I do to stop him doing this?
And to prevent many girls from getting affected by this teacher?

Comment: Can I ask what the downvotes are for?  This is a serious issue which all academics can suffer with.

Comment: @Chris (1) We do not handle high school problems. (2) The post contains _sh*t_ qualified for rude/abusive flagging. The question is automatically downvoted by the flags.

Comment: @scaaahu so easily edited that word - hope the OP accepts it...

Comment: @Chris I really hope she gets a solution...

Comment: @SolarMike - I hope so too

Comment: @Chris "10 std" in the question presumably means "10th grade" rather than "10 years old".

Comment: Ah I see @Pont.  So 14-15 years old.  Still has a right to be treated well no matter what age.

Comment: @Chris I feel this is probably a case that needs to be thrashed out on meta, since the question **is** blatantly off-topic as far as I can see. If there's a consensus that "anything is on-topic if OP's problem is drastic enough", I'd be happy to abide by that, but it would be useful to have that discussion in a single place on meta, rather than repeating it in the comments every time there's a similar case.

Comment: @Chris An additional problem is that, due to the asker's age, the appropriate solution and handling would likely differ from how an adult should approach this.  For example, young abuse victims would probably be well-advised to find a trusted adult as their primary response, whereas an adult going through a similar situation would be better advised on how to deal with it themself (even if that solution pathway would still be to, say, call the police or otherwise seek help from other members of the community).

Comment: @Chris All academics can also suffer from cancer, or a car accident. This is not a reason for a question to be asked in this site. The context must be relevant to academic issues.

Comment: Meta discussion: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4003/20058

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you should report it directly to the police.

Why, well, as he has been dismissed from the school they have no control over him, so reporting it to the school will only be for information.

You can choose to tell or not your parents but you may value their support.

I hope this sorts itself out. Best wishes.

Comment: Reporting to Police is definitely an option and so is reporting to the school.  The school has a responsibility and duty of care to their students.  They can support the student whilst reporting the teacher to the authorities and notify other child safeguarding authorities.

Comment: @Chris I agree that the school has a duty of care to their students but they don't control an ex-teacher. The police will know of all the possibilities of what support organisations exist, however, not all police forces are the same.

Answer (score 8):

**Tell your parents**.

If my Googling is accurate, then 10th grade in India is about 15-16 years old. That's below adult age. Accordingly, don't try to resolve the problem yourself, tell your parents (or guardians) and let them resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Following points may help you to get rid of it:

1. First and most important step is stop communication. Never reply to calls nor messages. Also never accept any kind of request from strangers in social networks nor reply to their messages. If they send message from a fake ID which looks similar to someone you know, then first confirm about it from the mutual friends or by phone calls before paying any attention to them.
2. Second step is tell to your parents, brothers and a lady teacher with whom you feel comfortable.
3. Third step is inform to your friends about it and tell them to stay away from that person and maintain distance.
4. Fourth step and may also be the very first step is inform to the head of your School about this matter and request to take possible action against him.
5. Last step is if nothing works for long time and things go to extreme, then report to police.

Hope this will help ....
Stay blessed!!

Comment: She has had enough slready - your point 5 is wait for a long time - really?? She has had enough and it needs to be sorted now at a different level than just ignore the messages...

Answer (score 2):

There is only one thing anyone can suggest and that is to report it.  Tell your parents or tell one of your teachers, and if they don't do something for you, then tell the Police.

You should not have to accept this behaviour.

The school has a responsibility and duty of care to their students.  They can support the student whilst reporting the teacher to the authorities and the school can notify other child safeguarding authorities to prevent them working in other schools

Answer (score 0):

1. Report this to the police.

   If you live in a place without legal protections in this regard, it's still helpful to push the boundaries.
2. It would have been helpful to apply a consistent non-response policy.  Given that you had trouble with this, I suggest handing your phone over to a trusted adult temporarily.
3. Please learn some basic online self-protection measures.  I noticed that you created a StackExchange user account with a first and last name, and you posted your age and the name of your town in your question.  Also, I wonder how the teacher found you online.  Here's a starting point: https://kidshealth.org/en/teens/online-id